# Highchart Slice color not updating Angular 2

Tags: angular, highcharts, pie-chart

I have used highchart api to build a pie chart, i am trying to change the color of my chart.

My Code Looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
const Highcharts = require('highcharts');

@Component({
    selector: 'pie-chart',
    templateUrl: './pie-chart.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./pie-chart.component.scss']
})
export class PieChartComponent implements OnInit {



    highchartsConfiguration: any = {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false,
            margin: [0, 0, 0, 0],
            spacingTop: 0,
            spacingBottom: 0,
            spacingLeft: 0,
            spacingRight: 0,
            events: {
                load: function (e) {

                    //document.getElementById("chart-text").remove();
                    let chart = this,

                        rend = chart.renderer,
                        pie = chart.series[0],
                        left = chart.plotLeft + pie.center[0],
                        top = chart.plotTop + pie.center[1];
                    if (this.rendTxt === undefined) {
                        this.rendTxt = rend.text('6.5h Avg', left, top).attr({
                            'text-anchor': 'middle', 'id': 'chart-text',
                            'font-size': '14px', 'font-weight': 'bold',
                        }).add();
                    } else {
                        this.rendTxt.attr({ text: '6.5h Avg' });
                        this.rendTxt.attr({ x: left });
                        this.rendTxt.attr({ y: top });
                    }

                },
                redraw: function (e) {

                    //document.getElementById("chart-text").remove();
                    let chart = this,

                        rend = chart.renderer,
                        pie = chart.series[0],
                        left = chart.plotLeft + pie.center[0],
                        top = chart.plotTop + pie.center[1];
                    if (this.rendTxt === undefined) {
                        this.rendTxt = rend.text('6.5h Avg', left, top).attr({
                            'text-anchor': 'middle', 'id': 'chart-text',
                            'font-size': '14px', 'font-weight': 'bold',
                        }).add();
                    } else {
                        this.rendTxt.attr({ text: '6.5h Avg' });
                        this.rendTxt.attr({ x: left });
                        this.rendTxt.attr({ y: top });
                    }

                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                size: 235,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                },
                center: ['30%', '30%'],
                showInLegend: true,
            }
        },
        legend: {
            align: 'center',
            layout: 'vertical',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            symbolRadius: 0,
            symbolHeight: 20,
            symbolWidth: 20,
            itemMarginTop: 25,
            itemMarginBottom: 2,
            y: 20,
            x: 100

        },
        series: [],
        responsive: {
            rules: [{
                condition: {
                    maxWidth: 500
                },
                chartOptions: {
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            size: 120,
                            center: ['50%'],
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        align: 'center',
                        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                        layout: 'horizontal',
                        symbolHeight: 20,
                        symbolWidth: 20,
                        itemMarginTop: 10,
                        itemMarginBottom: 5,
                        y: 0,
                        x: 0,

                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }]
        }

    };



    constructor() { }



    series = [];

    ngOnInit() {

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            colors: ['black', 'black', 'black', 'black']
        });



        this.series = this.series = [{
            // colors: [
            //     'blue',
            //     'black',
            //     'yellow',
            //     'green'
            // ],
            innerSize: '70%',
            data: [{
                name: '0 - 4 hours',
                y: 56.33
            }, {
                name: '4 - 8 hours',
                y: 24.03
            }, {
                name: '8+ hours',
                y: 10.38
            }, {
                name: 'Abnormalities',
                y: 4.77
            }]
        }]

    }

}
```

I have tried to change the color as per the solutions available on the web, But, none of the solution is working for me, my legends color are getting changed but pie chart slice color is still the default one.

> Legends color are getting change but, slice color is still same

Please suggest me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you make a live example, e.g. on plunkr? If you use point.update() method, both the point and its associated element in the legend will be updated - see the example http://plnkr.co/edit/iLCyLgvjQKbUNmg6ST5S?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer. After deep investigation and google search i found the cause of this problem was the css of high chart which was placed inside angular-cli.json . It was overriding the css property which i was putting for colors and overriding it with its default property. I removed the css property which is pointing to highchart.css file and my chart is now rendered with the color which i am passing.